# Why do I get segmentation fault sometimes, and sometimes not, using semaphores?

Tags: c, operating-system

Like title says, when I start ubuntu terminal first time after I start my computer it works fine but after I compile my program I'm getting segmentation fault error. Not sure if it's worth to mention but I use ubuntu on windows 10.
My semaphore.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h> /* for O_* constants */
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* random */
#include <unistd.h> /* sleep */
#define SHMSIZE 128
#define SHM_R 0400
#define SHM_W 0200


float getRandom(float min, float max) {
    // this function returns a random number between min - max
    float scale = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    return min + scale * (max - min);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *semName1 = "my_sema1";
    const char *semName2 = "my_sema2";

    struct shm_struct {
        int buffer[10];
        // unsigned empty;
        int next_in, next_out;
    };
    volatile struct shm_struct *shmp = NULL;
    char *addr = NULL;
    pid_t pid = -1;
    int var1 = 0, var2 = 0, shmid = -1;
    struct shmid_ds *shm_buf;

    /* init semaphores */
    sem_t *sem_id1 = sem_open(semName1, O_CREAT, O_RDWR, 10);
    sem_t *sem_id2 = sem_open(semName2, O_CREAT, O_RDWR, 0);
    int i, status;

    /* allocate a chunk of shared memory */
    shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, SHMSIZE, IPC_CREAT | SHM_R | SHM_W);
    shmp = (struct shm_struct *) shmat(shmid, addr, 0);
    // shmp->empty = 0;
    pid = fork();

    /* index in buffer */
    shmp->next_in = 0;
    shmp->next_out = 0;

    if (pid != 0) {
        /* here's the parent, acting as producer */
        while (var1 < 100) {
            float random_time = getRandom(0.1, 2.0); /* random between [0.1s - 2.0s] */
            usleep(random_time * 1000000); // sleep

            sem_wait(sem_id1); // locks the sem, decreases its value    
            var1++;
            printf("Sending %d\n", var1); fflush(stdout);
            shmp->buffer[shmp->next_in] = var1;

            shmp->next_in = shmp->next_in + 1 % 10;
            sem_post(sem_id2);
        }
        sem_close(sem_id1);
        sem_close(sem_id2);
        wait(&status);
        sem_unlink(semName1);
        sem_unlink(semName2);
        shmdt(addr);
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, shm_buf);
    } else {
        /* here's the child, acting as consumer */
        while (var2 < 100) {
            float random_time2 = getRandom(0.1, 2.0); /* random between [0.1s - 2.0s] */
            usleep(random_time2 * 1000000); // sleep
            sem_wait(sem_id2);
            var2 = shmp->buffer[shmp->next_out];
            printf("Received %d\n", var2); fflush(stdout);
            shmp->buffer[shmp->next_out] = -1; // remove
            shmp->next_out = shmp->next_out + 1 % 10;
            sem_post(sem_id1);
        }
        sem_close(sem_id1);
        sem_close(sem_id2);
        shmdt(addr);
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, shm_buf);
    }
}
```

Other than that, I'm trying to implement a bounded buffer with two semaphores where the producer puts items in buffer and customer reads them, does this code make sense? I don't see why I'm getting segmentation error.

Comment: "Why do I get segmentation fault sometimes, and sometimes not" that tends to happen when you have access violations. Try using a debugger or a dynamic analyzer like valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab a this with my little magic-8 ball:

```
sem_t *sem_id1 = sem_open(semName1, O_CREAT, O_RDWR, 10);
```

So the semaphore is initialized to 10.

```
pid = fork();

/* index in buffer */
shmp->next_in = 0;
shmp->next_out = 0;
```

`next_in` and `next_out` get set to 0 by both parent and child. This can happen at different times after the fork() for parent and child. *RACE CONDITION waiting to happen*.

```
        sem_wait(sem_id1); // locks the sem, decreases its value
```

We know sem_id1 is 10 so this never blocks for the first 10 loops.

```
        shmp->buffer[shmp->next_in] = var1;
        shmp->next_in = shmp->next_in + 1 % 10;
```

Three accesses to `next_in` that are not guarded from the initialization by the child. So you might enqueue 10 numbers or anywhere in those first 10 loops the `next_in` gets reset to 0 and you overwrite stuff.

```
if (pid != 0) {
} else {
}
```

What if pid is -1 because `fork()` failed? The parent would wait forever on `sem_id2`.

Your shared buffer isn't volatile. If the compiler can reason out that the buffer can't be aliased by `sem_id1` and `sem_id2` and maybe a few others it could just fill the buffer with {90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99} at the end of the loop.

On a even lower level you have no memory barriers. Just because one CPU core was told to write `var1` to memory in no way means that this becomes observable by other cores. First the value lands in the CPUs write buffer, then the L1 cache, then L2, then L3 and finally in main memory. If it gets flushed out at all. It could never leave the write buffer or stay in L1 cache for the duration of the program. It probably works on x86 but probably fails on everything else.

Lots of undefined behavior there but nothing I would expect to segfault. Ask your debugger to tell you where it faults.

But then I see this in both the parent and the child:

```
    shmdt(addr);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, shm_buf);
```

From the manpage:

> The caller must be the owner or creator of the segment, or be privileged.

The parent is the only owner of the shared memory segment and it will be destroyed. But the child is potentially still running and tries to access the buffer. Overall you return and free it twice.

I believe you have to move the call to

```
shmp = (struct shm_struct *) shmat(shmid, addr, 0);
```

after the fork so the shm_nattch gets incremented by both the parent and child and later decremented by each. That would be my guess for the segfault.

Update: sem_post() probably includes a full memory barrier so that might actually flush everything to main memory.